# Spring security with thymeleaf and ajax call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I use spring boot with spring-security

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/email",
                    "/starter**",
                    "/forgetpassword**",
                    "/resetpassword**",
                    "/register**",
                    "/register/**",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout();

}
```

I want to do ajax call to save information

```
@PostMapping("/book")
public ResponseEntity generateBook(@RequestBody Book book){

}
```

I tried this but i get a 403

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/book',
    type : 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    headers:{
        '_csrf' : '[[${_csrf.token}]]',
        '_csrf_header' : '[[${_csrf.headerName}]]'
    },
    data : '....',
    success : function(response) {
        debugger;
        ...
    }
});
```

I enabled spring security log with that

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Edit

I get this

> Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/book
> Responding with 403 status code

I just don't understand why?

the value of the token is generated by the server

Edit 2

Scenario is

User log to the system, he arrive on page with a button, When He click generate book start.

Generate book fail, if user try to change its password, i see the same csrf token value than the one created by

```
[[${_csrf.token}]]
```

Comment: And your spring security debug logs tell you that the reason for it is?

Comment: i updated the thread and provided informaiton asked

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to head tag:

```
<meta id="_csrf" name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta id="_csrf_header" name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

And in the AJAX request:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
//Add beforeSend to the ajax call, like:
$.ajax({
       type: ‘POST’,
       url: url,
       beforeSend: function(request) {
           request.setRequestHeader(header, token);
       },
       data: data
});
```